# CQ5.6.1 - Error while reading xml file in CQ from servlet in OSGi bundle

Tags: xml, servlets, aem, filenotfoundexception, osgi-bundle

I am working on a CQ5.6.1 in Windows 8. I am using a servlet which is deployed in an  OSGi bundle. From the servlet, I am trying to open an xml file which is stored in the path /etc/clientlibs/geometrixx of CQ. This is my code that I am using to read.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
...

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document amSetupDoc = null ;
amSetupDoc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("/etc/clientlibs/geometrixx/am/BaseAMStock_Settings.xml"));
```

At this point, I am getting the following exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\etc\clientlibs\geometrixx\am\BaseAMStock_Settings.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I have no idea why the path got converted to a windows path. Is there a better way to read a file in the CQ repository from my servlet? I appreciate any suggestions you can give me. Thanks.

Comment: There are different methods to read a file from a stream did you googled them ? You may refer this http://www.wemblog.com/2011/10/how-to-read-external-file-in-cq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I was working on similar functionality, I used `javax.jcr.Session` and `javax.jcr.Node`. Additionally, notice that all your data are not stored in `/etc/clientlibs/geometrixx/am/BaseAMStock_Settings.xml`, but in the property `jcr:data` of the sub-node called `jcr:content`.

You can easily check this using CRXDE: `http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp#/etc/clientlibs/geometrixx/am/BaseAMStock_Settings.xml`

Try the following sample of code:

```
String path = "/etc/clientlibs/geometrixx/am/BaseAMStock_Settings.xml/jcr:content";
if(session.nodeExists(path)) {
    Node node = session.getNode(path);
    if(node.hasProperty("jcr:data")) {
        Property jcrData = node.getProperty("jcr:data");
        //here you can use one of the methods from javax.jcr.Property:
        // - jcrData.getBinary().getStream();
        // - jcrData.getString();
    }
}
```